# Display Projection in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I'm looking for a way to quickly refer to the projection I have set for a map without clicking through the Properties.

Is there a setting to turn on a display element which will show the current map's projection?

Comment: Most folks know the projection of their map canvas. If they don't, then it's available in the properties. I guess you could make a toolbar to do this, but it doesn't seem like it would have enough demand to make it into a new feature

Comment: If you're in a layout, there's a dynamic text element for 'Spatial Reference'

Comment: @Vince I've got a bunch of places to map in one project. If it was just one projection to remember? Sure - easy to remember, but 45? I couldn't if I tried! That's why I was hoping for a little active display at the bottom of the map window.

Comment: @Brennan Yes. I'm using that in the layout, but before I get there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do here is just rename your map frame to include the projection used for that map (ex. "Working Map 02 (UTM 14)").

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the idea for a workaround. Seems like the feature doesn't exist.